# Apache Beam Wait.on JdbcIO.write with unbounded PCollection issue

Tags: java, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I am trying use the below scenario with unbounded pCollection datasource(PubSub).
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BEAM-6732

I am able to write to DB1. 
DB2 is having a Wait.on DB1 (PCollection .withResults). But unfortunately DB2 is not getting updated.

When I change the source to a bounded dummy PCollection, it works.
Any input is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned on Jira, do you have any Windows using in your unbounded pipeline?
The writing to another database starts only after the respective window has been fully written to the first database. Otherwise, it will wait forever.

Comment: Hi Alexey , sorry for late response. We had to switch to hibernate based implementation due to some other dependencies. So dropped investigating it further. But yes, the windowing was the problem.

Comment: Thanks for response, Ankit!

Comment: Hello, I have a similar situation, but instead of writing to another DB, I am waiting for the DB writes to complete to generate notifications back to Pub/Sub denoting that writes were successful. I am not using any windowing, other than the default one.

Comment: @asp What is your input source?

Comment: Hi @alexey-romanenko, my input is a Pub/Sub subscription (`PubsubIO.readStrings()`).

Comment: Also, just to elaborate, I did try a fixed window and was still not able to get this to work. I have added a few more details in https://stackoverflow.com/q/63663109/94354