# JdbcIO.Write.withResults and Wait.on with an unbounded PCollection with FixedWindow

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I am trying to implement a pipeline that is similar to the one outlined in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58464172/apache-beam-wait-on-jdbcio-write-with-unbounded-pcollection-issue), but unlike the situation mentioned in [BEAM-6732](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BEAM-6732), my source is a Pub/Sub subscription, and instead of using the `Wait.on` to write to another table, I am trying to use it to determine when the writes are complete, generate a message and route to a Pub/Sub topic.

I tried using the default window, but based on the documentation for `Wait.on`, it does not work for unbounded collections, tried manually defining a fixed window, with a lower allowed lateness, but that also does not seem to work, please find the window used below. The steps after the JDBCIO.write seems to be always stuck, i.e there is no output from the wait step.

```
Window.into(FixedWindows.of(Duration.standardSeconds(10)))
    .triggering(
        Repeatedly.forever(
            AfterProcessingTime.pastFirstElementInPane().plusDelayOf(Duration.standardMinutes(1))
                .orFinally(AfterWatermark.pastEndOfWindow())
        )
    ).withAllowedLateness(Duration.standardMinutes(2)).discardingFiredPanes();
```

Looking for advise on what could be wrong, also what the impact would be of using a low `allowedLateness` for a Pub/Sub source, which does not guarantee ordering.

Comment: Which PCollections are you applying the windows to? It might help if you put a larger code sample showing the layout around your Wait transform. Also the triggers might not affect Wait.on, since the [documentation](https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.23.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/transforms/Wait.html) mentions that it waits until the window is closed before signalling to continue (which includes the 2 minutes of lateness).

Comment: Hi @DanielOliveira, sorry I missed this, I will try to update the example above with more code snippets, but as mentioned in the question, the PCollection I am waiting on is a `WriteVoid` result from `JdbcIO.Write`, and the PCollection I use within that is the input from PubSub.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that Wait can be used for unbounded sources since it can be applied to on Windows. In [Wait SDK documentation](https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.23.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/transforms/Wait.html) we find:

> "returns a PCollection with contents identical to the input, but
> delays producing elements of the output in window W until the signal's
> window W closes (signal's watermark passes W.end +
> signal.allowedLateness)"

Let's look at the explanation `"apply T to X after Y is ready" -> X.apply(Wait.on(Y)).apply(T)`. If I understand correctly, we can adapt the following to your use case:

- T = Generate a message
- Y = JdbcIO.Write.withResults
- X = Emit to PubSub

While FixedWindow might be required in your code snippet, I think triggering won't be needed since Wait is already considering the end of the Window (signal's watermark passes W.end + signal.allowedLateness). Additionally, with a low value for allowedLateness, the Window will be closed sooner, as soon as the Window ends.

Comment: Thank you for the response, I actually got rid of wait since I was not able to get it to work, I remember trying with just the window without a trigger, and it was not triggering the downstream processes, will try to revert to this and update here.